# Error with structure definition: field ‘myaiocb’ has incomplete type

Tags: c++

I get the following error from compiling the below:

any ideas please?

```
struct cache_ent {
    struct aiocb myaiocb;           
#ifdef _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE `enter code here`
#if defined(__CrayX1__)
    aiocb64_t myaiocb64;        
#else
    struct aiocb64 myaiocb64;       
#endif 
#endif 
    long long fd;               
    long long size;             
    struct cache_ent *forward;      
    long long direct;           

    char *real_address;         

    volatile void *oldbuf;          

    int oldfd;              
    size_t oldsize;             
};
```

the error message is as follows:
-->error: field ‘myaiocb’ has incomplete type struct aiocb myaiocb; 
                   ^
-->error: field ‘myaiocb64’ has incomplete type struct aiocb64 myaiocb64;  /* For use in large file mode */

Comment: And what is `aiocb`? And where is its declaration?

Comment: a structure declared in a separate header file..imported to this one http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/aio.7.html

Comment: typedef struct aiocob {
               int             aio_fildes;     /* File descriptor */
               off_t           aio_offset;     /* File offset */
               volatile void  *aio_buf;        /* Location of buffer */
               size_t          aio_nbytes;     /* Length of transfer */
               int             aio_reqprio;    /* Request priority */
               struct sigevent aio_sigevent;   
               int             aio_lio_opcode;                                                   //lio_listio() only */
           };

Comment: Okay, but you use `aiocb` in your code, and in comment struct is `aiocOb`

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely missing an `#include` for the header file `unistd.h` - this is where `struct aiocb64` should be defined.

Comment: i doesnt look to be the problem. i have explicitly defined the struct aiocob, and still the same error. could it be that the compiler is complaining not about the data type, but the variable declaration itself..may be because the size of the myaiocob is not identified at compile time? I, have edited the question to include the definition of aicob struct